# Unsupported driver MongoDB in Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am new to `Mongo` and `Laravel`. I have been following [this](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) tutorial and when I call `all` method in my controller, it gives me the error **Unsupported driver [mongodb]**
Below is my controller and model
Controller:

```
class homeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users  = \App\Homemodel::all();
      $config_items = \App\Homemodel::getData();
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($users);
    }
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class Homemodel extends Eloquent
{


    protected $connection   =   'mongodb';

    protected $collection   =   'user';



    public static function getData() {
        echo "in all function";
    }


}
```

Comment: did you installed [mongodb](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php) driver for php ?